# Swift NSValue.valueWithCGRect

Tags: facebook, animation, swift, facebook-pop

I'm trying to animate the bounds of a UIButton using Facebook pop POPSpringAnimation, but I can't find what I should use in swift in replace of NSValue.valueWithCGRect

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender : UIButton) {

    var springAnimation = POPSpringAnimation()
    springAnimation.property = POPAnimatableProperty.propertyWithName(kPOPLayerBounds) as POPAnimatableProperty
    springAnimation.springBounciness = 12.0
    springAnimation.springSpeed = 10.0

    springAnimation.toValue = NSValue.valueWithCGRect(newBounds)

    shutterButton.pop_addAnimation(springAnimation, forKey: "size")

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will compile:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 1,height: 1)
let val = NSValue(CGRect: rect)
```

This is "initializer syntax"

Comment: Where is this documented? I don't get results for this with autocomplete either

Comment: @rounak: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_27

Comment: Yeah, I know about the conversion of method names, but I assumed this would be documented in the Swift NSValue header or docs.

Comment: @rounak it's hidden in the Swift UIGeometry header, you can get to it by option-clicking the `CGRect` portion of the call in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
func scaleView(view: UIView, magnitude: CGFloat) {
    var springAnimation = POPSpringAnimation()
    springAnimation.property = POPAnimatableProperty.propertyWithName(kPOPViewScaleXY) as POPAnimatableProperty
    springAnimation.springBounciness = 12.0
    springAnimation.springSpeed = 10.0

    let newRect = CGRect(x: (view.bounds.origin.x + (view.bounds.size.width / 2.0)) - ((view.bounds.size.width / 2.0) * magnitude), y: (view.bounds.origin.y + (view.bounds.size.height / 2.0)) - ((view.bounds.size.height / 2.0) * magnitude), width: view.bounds.size.width * magnitude, height: view.bounds.size.height * magnitude)

    springAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(CGRect: view.bounds)
    springAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect: newRect)
    view.pop_addAnimation(springAnimation, forKey: "size")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
    let hover = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    hover.additive = true
    hover.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointZero)
    hover.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(0.0, -10.0))
    hover.autoreverses = true
    hover.duration = 0.2
    hover.repeatCount = Float(Int.max)
    button.layer.addAnimation(hover, forKey: "myHoverAnimation")
```